# Downloading a file from WebClient not working c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to automatically download a subtitle file from www.addic7ed.com but when I try to do this:

```
WebClient t = new WebClient();
t.DownloadFile(@"http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/1/80504/0", 
               @"C:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Proyectos\Subtitulos\Subs1.srt");
```

It downloads the source code from the webpage.

If I try to access "http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/1/80504/0", it redirects me to the "select your download page".

However it is the hyperlink for such download. I think that the page detects if I am actually clicking the button or if I just have the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to download file it require referer header, try add

```
t.Headers.Add("Referer","http://www.addic7ed.com/serie/Modern%20Family/5/6/addic7ed");
```

Comment: YES!, That was it, I found the referer in fiddler, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

`WebClient` is working just fine. The behavior you're experiencing is part of the website.

The URL you're accessing sounds like a download site? It probably expects some cookies or headers to be set from a previous page to give you access to the full file. Maybe use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to figure out the traffic created by your browser and try to emulate it.

Comment: When I click on the link it shows this: GET http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/1/80504/0 
200 OK (text/srt), When I just open the link it shows this: GET http://www.addic7ed.com/updated/1/80504/0
302 Found to http://addic7ed.com/serie/Modern Family/5/6/addic7ed

Comment: Right, now drill down into the request, it should show you exactly what headers were sent.